# CSS Help with Padding on Hover Mac/FF 6

Tags: css

I have an interesting blinking problem on Hover with Mac/FF 6

To replicate:
* Size your window so that the word "Glass" (in "Black-Painted Glass") is not visible.
* You only see "Black-Painted".
* Now, hover your mouse over "Black-Painted" moving left and right.  For me, the cursor flickers between the arrow icon and pointer icon.
* If I hover over "Insulated Glass Units" and then hover on "Black-Painted" and stop moving the mouse... then I really get some serious blinking action.

The issue, I believe, exists because the hover has a padding-right; the window has a min-width which also contributes to this blinking effect.  Lastly, if I remove the ul from the CSS on line 5

```
html, body, div, span, ul, li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}


#nav-mid li.j:hover {
padding-right: 8px !important;
margin-left: -1px;
padding-left: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

the min-width seems to be ignored, and naturally, no more blink.  I can't reproduce in fiddle, but it's here: http://www.silverica.com/oops/ribbon-blink/

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can just increase the `min-width` on `body` a bit to compensate.

`min-width: 870px` works for me.

There no harm in changing it from `860px`, because it's still less than the commonly used `960px`.